# SQL getting one of each entries from left table and treating existence in the right as a boolean

Tags: mysql, sql, lamp

So I have achieved the results I want, but want to know if there is a better / cleaner way to do it:

```
SELECT * from Services
LEFT JOIN SellerServices ON SellerServices.Type = Services.Type    
WHERE `id` =$user_id
OR
 Services.Type NOT IN
  (
    SELECT  SellerServices.Type
    FROM     SellerServices
    where id =$user_id
  )
```

This returns all entries from the left table (Services in this case).

I can test later whether `$user_id = id field` in the results to set a check box to on or off in my html output, but what I've done seems a little kludgy and convoluted.

Does anybody know a cleaner way?

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?

Comment: Type Description id Type Details
1 Breaking NULL NULL NULL
2 Fixing NULL NULL NULL
3 Selling 1 3 
4 Acting 2 4 Acting Crazy
5 Programming 1 5 
6 Hardware Hacking NULL NULL NULL
7 Spying 1 7 
8 Writing 2 8 Writing 

with spraypaint on the walls
9 Confusing 3 9 
10 Mining 3 10

are the results of my query when I set $user_id to 1

(If you hit edit... you should be able to read that reasonably well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query returns the expected result, here is the same query with juste few adjustments (may be more performant):

```
SELECT S.*
    ,CASE
       WHEN S.id = $user_id THEN 'ON'
       ELSE 'OFF'
    END AS is_user
FROM Services S
LEFT JOIN SellerServices SS ON SS.Type = S.Type
LEFT JOIN SellerServices SSU ON SSU.id = S.id
                              AND SSU.Type = S.Type
WHERE S.id = $user_id
    OR SSU.id IS NULL
```

Instead of using a subquery, i've added a second jointure with table `SellerServices` using the same conditions as your subquery. The `WHERE` clause is then much more readable, i check if the `id` is matching the user id and if not, i check if the second jointure exists.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: SELECT * , CASE WHEN SS.id =1 THEN 'ON' ELSE 'OFF' END AS is_user FROM Services S LEFT JOIN SellerServices SS ON SS.Type = S.Type WHERE SS.id =1 OR SS.id IS NULL OR SS.id != 1 

works well... (based on your answer) I like it better than my subquery. But now that you see it written in this format, perhaps you know how to simplify it further I want all rows regardless of null, matching or not matching to be returned by the query.

Comment: @3pi14 Here you're testing `SS.id = 1 OR SS.id IS NULL OR SS.id != 1` but if you want every result why not simply remove the conditions on `SS.id`?

Comment: I was actually mistaken.... my revised query doesn't work, (yes I did think of using where 1 or where null)... but same problem so what I ended up doing was using the case syntax I learned from your query in my original query.... the not in subquery gives me 1 line for each non existant or non equal to $user_id, and so I get 1 line for each of the Services.  I'm not sure if there is another way to do it, perhaps with more advanced SQL.  I think I saw a keyword unique when I was originally trying to solve this.

Comment: @3pi14 i suggest you to create a new question for your new query with the description of what you've tried and if there is a better way to get the expected result, you'll be fixed ;-)

Comment: Well... I'm not that keen to spend time improving something that works well, but I may repost the question when I'd rather post questions than work on my project.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
select s.*,
       (exists (select 1 from SellerServices ss on ss.Type = s.type) ) as ExistsFlag
from services s
where s.id = $userid;
```

This chooses all rows (and columns) form `services`.  It adds a boolean if the `type` exists in the second table.

Comment: Yes... if that worked, but it didn't.  I am using MySQL, and that gave me an SQL Syntax Error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  * , 
CASE 
WHEN SS.id =1
THEN  'ON'
ELSE  'OFF'
END AS is_user
FROM Services S
LEFT JOIN SellerServices SS ON SS.Type = S.Type
WHERE SS.id =1
OR SS.id IS NULL 
OR SS.id != 1
```

(This is based on "https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975214/jo%c3%abl-salamin" 's answer)

but this gives the results I want and I think it is more readable... I don't know whether it is better on performance or not, but it's a small dataset, so it won't matter in this case.